# ListView Django -next prev links in pagination is missing

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-class-based-views

I working on pagination with `ListView` with django.
Everything is working as expected. But there is no next and previous links on template.

Am i missing something here ?

Here is urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from demoapp.models import Candidate
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^test/', ListView.as_view(
                    model=Candidate,
                    paginate_by='10',
                    queryset=Candidate.objects.all(),
                    context_object_name="tasks",                
                    template_name='index.html')),
)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
class Candidate(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

And here is index.html

```
<ol>
{% for t in tasks %}
<li><p>{{t.name}}</p></li>
{% endfor %}
</ol>
<div class="pagination">
      <ul>
          {% if paginator.has_previous %}
              <li><a href="?page={{ paginator.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a></li>
          {% endif %}
          {% for pg in paginator.page_range %}
              {% if posts.number == pg %}
                  <li class="active"><a href="?page={{ pg }}">{{ pg }}</a></li>
              {% else %}
                  <li><a href="?page={{ pg }}">{{ pg }}</a></li>
              {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
          {% if paginator.has_next %}
              <li><a href="?page={{ paginator.next_page_number }}">Next</a></li>
          {% endif %}
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing shows up because Django doesn't know what `paginator` is, in the view template.

Looking at [the example in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view), it seems you need to replace `paginator` in the view with `tasks` -

```
<div class="pagination">
  <ul>
      {% if tasks.has_previous %}
          <li><a href="?page={{ tasks.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a></li>
      {% endif %}
      {% for pg in tasks.page_range %}
          {% if posts.number == pg %}
              <li class="active"><a href="?page={{ pg }}">{{ pg }}</a></li>
          {% else %}
              <li><a href="?page={{ pg }}">{{ pg }}</a></li>
          {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% if tasks.has_next %}
          <li><a href="?page={{ tasks.next_page_number }}">Next</a></li>
      {% endif %}
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks tried this but still there is no next and perv button.

Comment: Your `paginate_by` parameter should be integer.

Comment: And you don't have specify both the `model` and `queryset` parameters. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/